# change activities in android FC

Tags: android

when i want to start new activity in my application , it just FC , code to change is  :

```
            myIntent = new Intent( this,about.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
```

and the about class is

```
    package com.arash.rz.webtar;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;


public   class about extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.about);

}
```

then , when in new main code i touch the menu that does the code , i got fc in emulator and or in the phone

Comment: Post the logcat showing the error.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add your second activity class in the manifest 
ex :

```
<activity android:name=".SecondActivityClass"/>
```

just add it after

```
</activity>
```